# How to re-sort option items in select drop down list?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple select drop down list that is bound by key/value pairs. However, the drop down list does not show option items in the order I want. Please help. Thank you.

I want it to show as follows:
10
20
30
50
100

However, it shows those option items as (100 is in the wrong place)

10
100
20
30
50

The following is my JS codes for my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('ListLogsModule', []);

myApp.controller('ListLogsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // the data is made in order I want.
    $scope.pageSizeOptions= {"10": "10", "20" : "20", "30" : "30", "50" : "50", "100" : "100"};
    // default selected item
    $scope.SelectedPageSize = "10";
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ListLogsModule" ng-controller="ListLogsCtrl">
        <span>Page Size:</span>

        <span>
            <select ng-model="SelectedPageSize" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in pageSizeOptions" >

            </select>
        </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the built in filter orderBy: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

You can also create your own filter to use: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters